# Contradictory statistics in news source?

Tags: distributions

Here are some interesting statistics at the bottom of a news [article](http://www.azcentral.com/story/money/business/health/2016/08/23/epipen-price-increase-massive-insurance-deductibles/89200034/) from today:

> "Up to 6% of children have food allergies, ..."
>   "Nearly nine in 10 schools nationally had one or more students with food allergies."

I readily found a 15-year-old [source](https://nces.ed.gov/pubs2001/overview/table05.asp) that showed that, for public schools at least, the average population of schools was generally high enough that most schools have a very high likelihood of food allergies, being on the order of as few as 160 and probability of allergy around 0.00005. Of course that table doesn't say anything about the distribution other than the mean or anything about non-public schools, which are likely to be smaller.

I find it very unlikely that there could be that many schools without allergies if the incidence rate is that high and a typical school has a few hundred students. Is there any relatively simple ways to (in)validate the plausibility of those two figures?

Comment: Do you have any data..?

Comment: @Tim There's a data table on the page I linked although I don't know how useful it all is for a quick and dirty examination of the problem. I'm not looking for somebody to do a deep analysis, just some back-of-the-envelope kind of approximation would be fantastic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about statistics but about validating news claims.

Comment: @Tim I'm not asking anybody to verify the data. I'm asking if there is a simple way to determine whether there's a distribution that would fit the numbers. I'm a mathematician and I believe this is a legitimate statistics question.

Comment: The first link is not freely available. Presumably you are referring to the United States specifically; this is an international forum and there is no default to one country. But that's a quibble, as I agree with the view that this is off-topic.  Questions based on obtaining data are off-topic here.

Comment: If the incidence rate is that high and incidence of allergies is random with respect to schools.

Comment: If one man is assessed for gonorrhea, his risk of contamination is low, but if many men provide a pooled urinalysis, the antibodies are more likely to turn up in the test.

Comment: @Nixk I've pulled all the relevant info from the article. If I hadn't posted it then somebody would have complained about that. My apologies if you feel that I'm wasting your time.

Comment: @AdamO I know. I computed `.94^160` to come up with that probability I mentioned.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Yes, I realize that we'd be assuming a random distribution of allergic students.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same initial reaction.  However, I think that a few very small schools can account for this.

Suppose that school size were distributed uniformly in log-space.  I don't know school size distribution statistics, but it wouldn't surprise me if this were the case.

I did a simple mathematical experiment, letting school sizes range from 5 to 5000 using 30 samples.  Then I took the mean probability over the 30 of having no children with allergies.  I got about 14%, which wasn't too far off the 1 in 10.

> > schls=5*10.^[0:0.1:3];
> >     mean(.94.^schls)

ans =

```
0.1357
```

Answer (score 2):

These results are highly consistent for moderately sized schools.

```
prob of school with at least 1 allergic child = 0.9
prob of school having no allergic child = 0.1

prob of allergic child = 0.06
prob of nonallergic child = 0.94
prob of 10 non allergic children = 0.94^10 
prob of 100 non allergic children = 0.94^100 = 0.002
```

Verifying other assumptions about school size, etc. is beyond the scope of the report. You wouldn't be able to falsify any findings without obtaining those data.